# Is there a way to combine css attribute selectors and first-of-type selectors and use them on a element

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-position, positioning

I have a table and a bunch of tr elements inside it. Some of them have different classes and others have different. Lets say, I have 7  elements, in which 5 of them have diff class names and the remaining 2 of them have diff class names and the position of the elements are random. Now I want to select the elements in the 2 diff class names separately. How could I do that.

EX:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="row"></tr>
    <tr class="grouping-row"></tr>
    <tr class="row"></tr>
    <tr class="row"></tr>
    <tr class="grouping-row"></tr>
    <tr class="row"></tr>
    <tr class="row"></tr>
</table>
</tbody>
```

From the above example, I want to select elements with the class name 'grouping-row' individually and apply styles to them.

***This is what I tried:***

table tbody tr[class="grouping-row"]:first-of-type , but it didn't work. And I cannot select them using nth-child() because the position of the elements are random.

Comment: You want to apply some css properties to class "grouping-row" right? You could add the same in the css itself, right.. So that it will be reflected in all elements using "grouping-row" class..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.grouping-row { color: red; }
.grouping-row ~ .grouping-row { color: yellow; }
```

Comment: Could you please brief me about the concept on this.

Comment: check this: https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling. Btw does it work?

Comment: That works, but say I have another 'grouping-row' element which I need to style differently, using this '~' combinator selects all the sibling elements, like if we have 3 elements, it selects the remaining 2 siblings, but I want to select only one.

Comment: Well in that case we have to make a selector by looking at the pattern of the elements. If that does not work then we need to add a separate class to that element.

Comment: To add separate classes also we need to select them right?

Comment: Yeah, but if you have such a situation right now and you are having problems with it, then you can edit the question and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code:

```
table .grouping-row
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, not like that, I want to apply specific style to the first 'grouping-row' element and a diff style to the second 'grouping-row' element.

Comment: Your answer is currently marked as low quality and faces deletion. Please make sure your answer contains an explanation aside from any code.